# Part No. of Micro USB connector used in Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: usb, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I would like to know the part No. of micro USB connector on-board the Raspberry Pi Zero & Zero W.
As per the schematic available under official Raspberry Pi documentation, it is listed as 690-005-298-486. However, when searched on digikey and other websites, it was found to be a USB Mini-A connector not USB micro B!!!

Anyone aware of the exact part no. pl. post it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a mistake, or perhaps the part is no longer available. Note that other Raspberries have [10103594-0001LF](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Amphenol-FCI/10103594-0001LF?qs=EnLMdcWnKABYZwdMsmC%2Fag%3D%3D) from Amphenol:

> Micro USB 2.0 B Receptacle STD, SMT+DIP

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Other Raspberries in the sense? 
Is the part mentioned above used on Raspberry Pi Zero board? I need the exact part number as I have a damaged Pi zero and would like to use these micro USB connectors on another custom PCB!

Comment: @RaghavanK That Amphenol part is used on Pi 2 / Pi 3. I don't have a Pi Zero so I can't say for sure, but from the pictures I see online it seems to have a similar receptacle. If you're building a custsom PCB, just buy the connectors you need. Why reuse a (potentially broken) connector from a non-working Pi?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi zero is dead but both the micro usb connectors on it are absolutely fine. So, thought of re-using them!